# Why does `pip install hwrt --upgrade` upgrade to a random version (sometimes also downgrade)?

Tags: python, pypi

I've just executed

```
$ sudo pip install hwrt --upgrade
```

to install the latest version of my Python package `hwrt`.
I've added the possibility to get the package version with `hwrt --version`.
Now I get this strange behavior:

```
$ hwrt --version
hwrt 0.1.201
$ sudo pip install hwrt --upgrade
[... some output ...]
$ hwrt --version
hwrt 0.1.203
$ sudo pip install hwrt --upgrade
[... some output ...]
$ hwrt --version
hwrt 0.1.205
$ sudo pip install hwrt --upgrade
[... some output ...]
$ hwrt --version
hwrt 0.1.200
```

What is happening here?

I have `pip 6.0.7 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

### Verbose

I've just ran `sudo pip install hwrt --upgrade --verbose > install.log`.

The full log is here: http://pastebin.com/eZ9M9UVd

The following seems to be interesting:

```
[...]
Using version 0.1.211 (<-this is the version it should be)[...]
[...]
Collecting hwrt from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/h/hwrt/hwrt-0.1.211.tar.gz#md5=b75ac2f4c644743cfa865f086163a93e
  "GET /packages/source/h/hwrt/hwrt-0.1.211.tar.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 2228910
  Downloading hwrt-0.1.211.tar.gz (2.2MB)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/h/hwrt/hwrt-0.1.211.tar.gz#md5=b75ac2f4c644743cfa865f086163a93e
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-lWJUXg/hwrt/setup.py) egg_info for package hwrt
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/hwrt.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/hwrt.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/hwrt.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/hwrt.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/hwrt.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/hwrt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/hwrt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/hwrt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /tmp/pip-build-lWJUXg/hwrt has version 0.1.211, which satisfies requirement hwrt from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/h/hwrt/hwrt-0.1.211.tar.gz#md5=b75ac2f4c644743cfa865f086163a93e
[...]
Found existing installation: hwrt 0.1.204
Uninstalling hwrt-0.1.204:
[...]
Successfully installed argparse-1.2.1 hwrt-0.1.209
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Perhaps, that's why they tell, *too much is too bad* ....

Comment: Maybe add in the `-v` / `--verbose` flag - it'll show you more exactly how it's determining which version you have and where it's finding the latest version. Also, your omitted `[... some output ...]` could contain some vital information for figuring this out. This certainly sounds like it could be a bug. Have you tried updating pip itself (`pip install --upgrade pip`?)

Comment: @moose - Looks like a bug to me. It clearly prints out that 0.1.211 is the newest version and so should be installed, but then at the end it says it installed 0.1.209 instead. I only skimmed over the rest, but I didn't see anything about conflicts occurring that would require an older version of hwrt.

Comment: Assuming this is a bug: is that now properly reported and kept track of?

Comment: Donald Stufft (PyPA) asked for the version, and you are using a quite recent pip version, so I guess this is worth a report. If you want to be responsible, check out the official pip bug tracker on https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues and try to find if that problem has already been reported there. If not, you should do so! You can also link to this SO thread. "Reporting bugs" on mailing lists or here on SO usually leads to nothing, because there is no back-reference.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I've just added it to the bug tracker https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2408

Comment: Did you use the pypi webform instead of `python setup.py upload` to upload your package? On PyPi the package appears as version 0.1.211 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hwrt) but in the `setup.py` file it states its version as 0.1.209 (https://github.com/MartinThoma/hwrt/blob/master/setup.py)

Comment: @MarcelStimberg I used `python setup.py upload`. The Github repository is not up-to-date.

Comment: @moose - that your github repository is not up to date might be the source of the problem. You are giving the address of the github repository in the `download_url` and maybe that's confusing pypi? Not saying it isn't a bug in pip as well, but removing the `download_url` argument might fix it (IIRC, `download_url` should rather point to a tar-ball/zip fall of the release for the given version, not to a general page).

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue...

Comment: Since you are the developer of the software, you may have installed it multiple times for testing. Your most recent log indicates that pip uninstalled a version of the software. Check sys.path and your site-packages directory, and clean out any old packages.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't answer the *why* that I think is your primary question, I can offer a solution to get around the problem if it's causing problems. The short version is just to specify exactly what version you want, e.g.:

```
trevor@nikola:~$ pip list --outdated | grep Django
Django (Current: 1.7.5 Latest: 1.7.6)
pip install -U Django==1.7.6
```

This is especially useful if you're creating something and you want to specify dependencies that remain static so you don't have to update your code if an underlying dependency changes.

Sometimes you're not sure which version is appropriate, such as knowing you need to use a version *"before version X"*, but don't know the specific number to install. Pip can show you the available versions if you try to install an incorrect/non-existent version. For example:

```
trevor@nikola:~$ pip install Django==-1
Collecting Django==-1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==-1 
(from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 
... lots that I'm skipping ... 
1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 
1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2)
  No distributions matching the version for Django==-1
```

So I know I need a pre-1.7 install, I can probably use 1.6.10.